# The set of all semi-magic squares is a subspace of the vector space of 3 × 3 matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, magic-square

I am interested in proving the following statement and would appreciate some guidance or help:

`The set of all semi-magic squares is a subspace of the vector space of 3 x 3 matrices.`

Where a matrix is said to be a **semi-magic square** if its row sums and column sums (i.e. the sum of entries in an individual row or column) all add up to the same number.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to verify that $\lambda A$ and $A+B$ satisfy the given condition provided that $A$ and $B$ does and $\lambda\in\Bbb R$.